# Fluent NHibernate - map a list of Enums using a custom mapping

Tags: c#, collections, enums, fluent-nhibernate, iusertype

In our solution, when mapping Enums, instead of simply saving the integer or text description, a custom `IUserType` is used to resolve the text description against a database table and retrieve the appropriate ID. (These values are cached at application start-up to speed things along)

This has been working really well for single Enum properties. The mapping code (using mapping overrides) looks something like this....

POCO:

```
  public class Connection
  {
      // Other properties omitted
      public Protocol Protocol { get; set; }
  }
```

Mapping Override:

```
  mapping.Map(map => map.Protocol, "ProtocolID")
         .CustomType<GenericEnumUserType<Protocol>>();
```

My problem occurs when I have a list of Enums to map. For example...

POCO:

```
  public class Credential
  {
      // Other properties omitted
      public ICollection<Protocol> Protocols { get; set; }
  }
```

My research ([here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15258635/map-a-collection-of-custom-types-on-fluent-nhibernate) and [here](http://programming.nullanswer.com/forum/4439640)) suggests the mapping should be similar to the following:

```
  mapping.HasMany(x => x.Protocols)
         .Table("TABLE")
         .KeyColumn("COLUMN")
         .Component(component =>
                   {
                           //MAP YOUR CUSTOM TYPE HERE
                   })
         .Cascade.None()
         .KeyNullable()
         .Not.LazyLoad();
```

... but I can't figure out how to wire up the `CustomType` in the `MAP YOUR CUSTOM TYPE HERE` section.

On the other hand, [this SO thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/978788/fluentnhibernate-and-enums) suggests `CustomType` is not available for collections - however that particular comment is dated 2009 so I'm hoping something has changed since then.

Should this type of mapping be possible (and if so what am I missing) or do I need to start looking for the most appropriate work-around?

Cheers.